# Get error when try to put string-funcs in f-string

Tags: python, f-string

```py
a = 'guindo , barwos, zasport'
a
```

```
guindo , barwos, zasport
```

But when I write

```py
print(f'find is {a.find('a')}')
```

I get error

> SyntaxError: f-string: unmatched '('

Why? Can someone please write right code that will be work. Thanks.

Comment: Starting with Python 3.12, your code will work as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(f"find is {a.find('a')}")
```